# Ставится ли запятая в сложном предложении перед союзом «или»?

Tags: запятые, спп

*Не исключено, что луг, который так любила ее мать, будет запущенным(,) или река будет отравленной.*

Comment: Исправьте предложение или заголовок , Александр. Пока не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете в виду. Ведь второго союза "что" нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не опечатались и вместо 'и луг' не должно быть 'или луг', то мы имеем обычное ссп с общей придаточной частью. И поскольку есть общая для двух простых предложений часть, **запятая не нужна** (Розенталь, Пунктуация, § 30.2.2).

Если же имеется в виду 'или луг', то запятая **нужна** — по правилу о повторяющихся союзах (там же, прим. 1).

Answer (score 0):

***Не исключено, что луг, который так любила ее мать, будет запущенным(,) или река будет отравленной.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя однородными придаточными.

Запятая не ставится, так как одиночный союз ИЛИ соединяет два придаточных изъяснительных предложения с союзами ЧТО (второй союз опущен).

**Примечание.**  Определительное придаточное с союзным словом «который» находится внутри первого изъяснительного придаточного и обособляется с двух сторон.

Правило Розенталя  § 35. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139
Пункт 3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится
Союз ИЛИ – это одиночный разделительный союз.